# Python jupyter library import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have installed Anaconda to use jupyter notebook.

After a while I installed cv2 library using cmd. It installed perfectly and works in normal cmd python window.

But when I'm trying to load cv2 library into my jupyter notebook, I'm getting an error;

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: The solution in above example not working.. and it's not the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you installed OpenCV into a different environment, try to install it again, using conda, into the environment in which you've got your Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Good post.